# Juntemos en respuestas wiki las respuestas cortas específicas de regiones / Let's use community wiki to summarize set of short region specific answers

Tags: discusión, respuestas-wiki

El idioma español tiene casi 500 millones de hablantes nativos, más de 20 millones de estudiantes y es oficial en 21 países (fuente: [Wikipedia sobre *idioma español*](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idioma_espa%C3%B1ol)). Este gran dominio lingüístico confiere al idioma una riqueza enorme en forma de variadísimos dialectos, múltiples palabras para definir los mismos conceptos, palabras que quieren decir diferentes cosas en distintos lugares, etc.

Los visitantes de [Spanish Language](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/) solemos tener orígenes distintos y esto se observa en las respuestas: con frecuencia una pregunta sobre el significado de una palabra da lugar a muchas respuestas, cada una dando detalles de una región específica.

Pero claro, tal y como dice el [Tour de Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/tour):

> This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum.
>   There's no chit-chat.

Y también [¿Qué tipo de preguntas puedo hacer aquí?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

> Pero por favor, **no preguntes** sobre los siguientes asuntos. Están
>   fuera del ámbito de este sitio.
>
> (...)
>
> - Preguntas sobre "listas", donde cada respuesta es igualmente válida.

Y allí es donde observamos cierto problema con preguntas interesantísimas que con el tiempo se desbordan: inicialmente se preguntó por el significado de una palabra en un lugar dado, pero poco a poco se han ido trufando de respuestas breves, apenas una frase, del tipo "pues en X lugar se dice/lo llamamos Y" o "pues en Z lugar la palabra quiere decir TTT".

He aquí algunas preguntas que tienen más de una decena de respuestas de este tipo:

- [How do you say a "shot" referring to alcohol?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/1969/1674)
- [¿Qué significa "sollado"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/4015/1674)

Toda información que recibimos es fácilmente digerible, pues la comunidad es pequeña y disponemos de muchas herramientas para procesarla correctamente: editar, votar para eliminar, convertir en comentarios;
Si una pregunta se convierte en especialmente "conflictiva" se puede llegar a [proteger la pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions), con lo que usuarios no registrados no pueden contestar libremente (necesitan al menos 10 puntos de reputación para hacerlo).
Sin embargo, esto también deja fuera la posibilidad de tenern respuestas interesantes por parte de gente que entrar espontáneamente al sitio.

Por ello, lanzo la siguiente propuesta doble:

- De futuro: intentemos que las preguntas sean lo más específicas posible, indicando la región a la que nos referimos cuando preguntemos. Para ello, también es bueno utilitzar las etiquetas creadas a tal efecto (existen de todos los países hispanohablantes).
- De actualización y puesta en orden de lo que ya tenemos: **en todas aquellas preguntas en las que a lo largo del tiempo se hayan ido produciendo tantas respuestas especificando información de una zona dada, creemos una [respuesta wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) para ir añadiéndolas, a la vez que eliminemos la respuesta corta**. De esta forma, el contenido será mucho más fácilmente concentrado, leíble y actualizable. Además, la existencia de múltiples respuestas con sus respectivos votos a favor y en contra genera una jerarquía de respuestas que no es necesaria, pues no son comparables entre sí; por contra, las respuestas wiki concentran todo el "saber" en un único lugar.

La labor importante es la segunda, la de crear respuestas wiki. Por ello, y antes de empezar, creo interesante ir detectando estas preguntas entre todos, para luego ir "limpiándolas". La labor de limpieza la podemos hacer los moderadores con facilidad, pues las herramientas con que Stack Exchange nos dispone permiten convertir una respuesta en comentario, en edición, etc, así como eliminar respuestas con un solo click (de lo contrario se necesitan tres votos de usuarios diferentes).

Yo calculo que podríamos hacerlo inicialmente en una veintena de preguntas, pasando de unas 10 respuestas cada una a apenas dos o tres (la wiki y alguna más). También deberían mirarse los comentarios para ver si hay también que incorporar información de allí.

Esta es una propuesta que me gustaría que se debatiera: ¿qué os parece? ¿dónde debería ponerse el umbral de calidad de respuesta para añadirla a la respuesta wiki?

Si la tiramos adelante, podemos hacerlo de forma progresiva. Si en algún momento vemos que no nos gusta, tenemos las herramientas para devolver todo a como estaba. Por tanto, no nos debe dar miedo intentarlo : )

¿Lo hacemos? ¿Con cuáles empezamos?

¡Gracias por leer hasta aquí!

Comment: Una duda: ¿esto es algo que pueden hacer solo los moderadores? Para un usuario estandar como yo, crear una pregunta wiki es un misterio. Recuerdo que años atrás había un botón.

Comment: @Rodrigo no, puede hacerlo cualquier persona con al menos 10 puntos de reputación ([Privileges - create wiki posts](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/community-wiki)) y editar con al menos 100 puntos ([fuente](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/209901)). Lo que pasa es que ahora no es un botón sino checkbox que aparece al redactar la respuesta; en el primer enlace puedes ver una imagen.

Comment: @Rodrigo si menciono a los moderadores es por la parte de eliminar respuestas, pues lo podemos hacer con un solo click, mientras que para el resto de usuarios requiere involucrar a más gente. Unir las respuestas en un community wiki es, efectivamente, algo que puede hacer cualquier persona.

Comment: Si globalmente estoy de acuerdo, aunque es una tarea colosal. Deberíamos hacer una lista de preguntas que son susceptibles a esta opéración para comenzar. (Si no comenzamos nunca se va a hacer)

Comment: @Joze haciendo una consulta del tipo [`is:q answers:7 views:2000`](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+answers%3A7+views%3A2000) obtenemos 47 resultados. Yo creo que es el tipo de condiciones que buscamos: preguntas con muchas respuestas y bastantes visitas. Seguro que algunos de los resultados no son del tipo que buscamos y que otras no aparecen en la lista, pero sería un buen inicio.

Comment: Sin oponerme a la intención final (en realidad todo lo contrario), hay que considerar que [How do you say a "shot" referring to alcohol?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/1969/1674) ha generado hasta el momento 14 respuestas y m/m 90 votos, mientras que [¿Balé o Ballet - Chalé o Chalet?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/12322/6915) (respuesta tipo wiki) ha generado 3 participaciones y 5 votos. De acuerdo, hay otros factores más importantes (lo interesante del tema, cuánto tiempo ha pasado), pero una respuesta de tipo wiki puede, creo, desincentivar la participación.

Comment: @Rodrigo puede haber distintos motivos para ello. Para empezar, la del "ballet" tiene apenas 275 visitas en un año, mientras que la del "shot" más de 35 mil en cuatro. Puede que la implicación sea contraria (como hay pocas respuestas, Google no lo presenta tan arriba en los resultados), pero me da a mí que las respuestas cortas que pretendo juntar vienen de google, a través de usuarios puntuales que seguramente no volverán. Sigo.

Comment: @Rodrigo Interesante punto el que comentas. La respuesta tipo wiki puede desincentivar a usuarios no registrados, pero también incentivar a los ya existentes a añadir su país si ven que no está presente en la lista. Al necesitarse apenas 10 puntos para hacerlo, puede incluso incentivar. Creo que lo más razonable sería hacer la siguiente prueba en dos preguntas con formato parecido: unificar en wiki en una y dejar como está en otra. Pasados los meses, comparar qué ha sucedido.

Comment: @fedorqui mi formación científica me lleva a pensar que un tamaño muestral de 1 es demasiado insuficente: el éxito o fracaso de una u otra va a depender excesivamente del interés específico que genere la pregunta concreta, y hasta de la manera -más o menos intuitiva- en que esté redactada

Comment: mirando los resultados de `is:q answers:7 views:2000`, se me viene a la cabeza que una buena veta es la pronunciación: yeísmo/lleísmo, seseo/ceceo, y la de los distintos niveles de formalidad y usos de la segunda persona singular: vos, usted y tú

Comment: @Rafael totalmente de acuerdo, si bien yo me estoy refieriendo a preguntas ya existentes con un gran volumen de visitas, respuestas y edad, todo ello de dimensión parecida entre ellas.

Comment: @Rafael interesante veta. Si todo va bien y la gente sigue pronunciándose a favor de esta iniciativa, había pensado durante el fin de semana hacer una pequeña selección de preguntas donde empezar a hacer esta "limpieza". Lo haría incluyendo una respuesta a esta pregunta para ir marcando el estado del proceso. Las que comentas podrían estar en esta lista.

Answer (score 1):

Respuestas wiki añadida y respuestas de una línea convertidas a comentarios a la respuesta wiki:

- [¿Qué significa "sollado"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/16914/1674)

Respuesta wiki añadida:

- [How do you say a “shot” referring to alcohol?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/16913/1674)
- [¿Qué es “inventar el hilo negro”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/16984/1674)
- [¿Se usa 'guácala' fuera de México?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17039/1674)
- [What does the word “pinche” mean?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17040/1674)
- [Fireworks en español](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17232/1674)
- [What's the best way to inform a pedestrian or fellow cyclist that I'm about to pass them?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17245/1674)
- [Definition of 'escuela' and 'colegio'](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17265/1674)
- [¿En qué paises aplica la acepción anatómica de “pito”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/10035/1674) - las otras respuestas eliminadas.
- [¿Cómo se dice regionalmente “coquetear”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/2344/1674)
- [Armpit: sobaco vs. axila](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/18186/1674)
- [How do I say “Silly me” in Spanish?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20565/1674)
- [How to translate “have a crush on somebody”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20566/1674)
- [Other Spanish synonyms to "Banana"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/1129/1674)
- [What is the diminutive of "pan" (meaning bread)?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/352/1674)
- [¿Cuáles son sinónimos de "ni fu ni fa"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/4520/1674)
- [Most accurate translation of “possum”](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/20614/1674)
- [¿En qué zonas se usa “A lo de mi abuela” o “Donde mi abuela” para referirse a “Voy a la casa de mi abuela”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23538/1674)
- [¿Cuál es la palabra más generalmente aceptada para decir “calzado deportivo”?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/17071/1674)

De momento no elimino las respuestas cortas, lo haré en breve.

---

Pendientes de revisar:

- [Most accurate translation of "possum"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/1359/1674)
- [How should I ask someone to repeat something they've said?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/523/1674)
- [¿Qué significa "tuanis"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/2806/1674)
- [What does "a la orden" mean?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/5551/1674)
- [What are the different words for "beer"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/1139/1674)

Comentario que añado:

Añado esta referencia de acuerdo con lo indicado en [Juntemos en respuestas wiki las respuestas cortas específicas de regiones](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2483/1674). Edita libremente para incluir la versión de tu país o región.

---

I am adding this summary following what was discussed in [Let's use community wiki to summarize set of short region specific answers](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2483/1674). Feel free to edit to add the term used in your country or region.

---