# CW answer for an old question with several upvoted answers: would it make sense?

Tags: discusión, respuestas-wiki

Because of a Late Answers review task, I found myself re-reading the answers to this old question: [How do you differentiate between walnuts and pecans in Spanish?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2879), and I was surprised to find that [***anacardo***](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anacardo) was not mentioned anywhere.
The question has several answers already, some of which have been upvoted many times (for our standards, I mean), and one is even accepted. I thought of editing one of them to include *"anacardo"*, but I'm not comfortable including new terms in other people's answers.

Now, the thing is that all the answers are similar in that they list the names for this or that country, which fits the scenario of [Juntemos en respuestas wiki las respuestas cortas específicas de regiones / Let's use community wiki to summarize set of short region specific answers](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2483). So maybe it'd be a good idea to **merge all the answers into a new CW answer** with the names for each country, which would be clearer and also easier to improve with new terms.
My question is: would it make sense to do that... now? The question is like 7 years old now, and there's no way for the OP to change their accept vote, nor for a new CW answer to get on top of the current ones unless these were deleted, which might be undesirable.

---

EDIT: [CW answer posted](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/31389), as per fedorqui's advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Despite not posting new questions, jrdioko (the OP) visits the site from time to time and has even [changed the accepted answer to one of their questions](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/posts/25644/timeline#vote_106157). So posting a CW with a summary of the country-specific answers seems very valid to me, and then commenting to the OP so they can accept the new one if they find it useful.

It could also be useful to talk to the user who posted the accepted answer, but they have not accessed the network for years now and that will probably be useless. Changing their answer in such a manner sounds a bit too much to me, also.

Once such CW has been posted, you can flag the one-line answers so they can be removed. Following what was commented in [Juntemos en respuestas wiki las respuestas cortas específicas de regiones / Let's use community wiki to summarize set of short region specific answers](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2483/1674), what we normally do is to convert them into a comment of the CW answer. Although it may look weird to have a comment with a timestamp way before the answer was posted, it is useful to track the information that was compiled in the CW.

Comment: The last part got too complicated for me!  But the basic answer (yes, go ahead and make a CW and then flag to request some clean-up) seems to me to work also for situations where the OP is no longer active.